# SQL lost in to escaping characters for INSERT statements

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005, escaping, quoting

- I am using Microsoft SQL **2005**.
- "Someone" gives me a list of `INSERT` "pre-defined statements" that I **CANNOT modify outside SQL** (e.g. using scripting languages like Python).
- Being the "Someone" I am having issues trying to **escape quoting characters** for fields of type `NVARCHAR`.

Say for example I need to run the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO TableX VALUES('John Doe's value') -- This is not working because of single quotes...
```

I need to find a way to transform that string to insert (`John Doe's value`) without using methods outside of SQL statements.

I unsuccesfully tried something like the following statements, concatenating a single quote with a `REPLACE` function and another single quote:

```
INSERT INTO TableX VALUES('' + REPLACE('John Doe's value'), ''', '''' + '')
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO TableX VALUES('''''' + REPLACE(''''''John Doe's value'''''''), '''''', '''''''' + '''''')
```

In order to deal with escaping characters, but it is not working.

I would prefer using functions or simple stuff like that rather than using stored procedures or more complex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you stop accepting INSERT statements and provide a stored procedure with well defined arguments and data types, if you are accepting in SQL server. Otherwise, you would be prone to injection attacks (I agree that no internal client to your API would do that but your API will be vulnerable, that's it!).

BTW, both functions and stored procedures are similar w.r.t the complexity involved in this case.

Comment: Yes, I should avoid that scenario. But sometimes you need to do like that, even if you know it's not the best approach, just because someone told you to do like that and you can't reverse the relatioship "master slave".

Comment: Though this argument doesn't help you, I think it is the responsibility of the master giving the "INSERT" statements to make sure they are well-formed, in such case. I see the "Slave" here no different than the DBMS itself where if as a master user, I give it an incorrectly formed SQL, it just can't execute and throws the error on my face :)

Comment: Sometimes real world is really complicated and solutions have an history in their background.
I am supposed to have those `INSERT` statements from a Mail Marge of MS Word with a MS Excel spreadsheet of data. This way is well established and tested (internal procedures among PMs, developers, QA department etc.). There is no way to escape for a "developer" (i.e. a new approach is going to increase costs...).
My solution is to use "find & replace" from MS Excel replacing a `'` with a `''`, fixing this issue.

I was wondering whether there would be a way much more close to a programmatic way...